# Generation of UML class diagram out of C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml, class-diagram

I have the following problem. I have some C# classes and I need an UML class diagram for that as documentation.
As I want to spare time and nerves it would be awesome if I can generate the diagram out of my code. (Reverse engineering tool)
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but in the UML tool there I can only draw them by hand or am I missing something?
I know there's such a tool in eclipse named object aid uml.
Something similar would fulfill my needs. 
EDIT:
View > Class view - is unfortunately not enough

Comment: In VS, click View > Class View. In Class View explorer you should be able to find all listed Class per Project, right click a Class and select View Class Diagram. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know this option, but this is no UML diagram, more a visualisation of C# classes.

Comment: I believe that is nearest you can get.

Comment: I agree with Dr. Stitch so you can create your diagram by hand or change the tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deeper research got me to this stackoverflow post from a Microsoft employee.
He clearly states that there's no intention to bring such a reverse engineering tool to Visual Studio 2015.

**Reference**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139082/3957817